# Nginx does not call php parser

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I'm trying to setup a php7 test server for an existing codebase. I seem to be hitting the php block in my adjusted server configuration as my nginx error log is reporting `upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/usr/local/phpbrew/php/php-7.1.13/var/run/php-fpm.sock` when I trying hitting the site and I've got the permissions bruises to show its looking for the socket where I expect it to. The site is served by fastcgi ontop of nginx.

However at the moment I'm getting my php served as plain unparsed text in browser and over curl for unclear reasons. Based on my searching it seems like my php handling in my nginx/conf.d/*.conf files is not entirely correct in some fashion. Can anyone see an issue with this block?

(note this is a snippet from a much larger file which contains exactly one reference to ~ .php$ on port 443.)

```
server {
  listen       443 ssl spdy;
  server_name  local.site.com xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx eth2.site.com "";

location ~ \.php$ {
    root /var/www/site;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/usr/local/phpbrew/php/php-7.1.13/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/mygagenet$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/my.site.net_error.log";
    include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  }
```

Comment: Try to move root path to server section after server_name

Comment: @Nikita No joy with that (w/ nginx and php-fpm restarts)